# How to do upsert in Zookeeper/Curator?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I would like to be able to update or create if it doesn't exist a node in Zookeeper. We are using Curator.

I could just do:

```
CuratorFramework client = ...
String path = "/my/interesting/path";
byte[] data = ...
client.createContainers(path);
client.setData(path, data);
```

But this isn't transactional. There's also inTransaction(), but that doesn't seem to have any methods like createContainers or even any way to check for existence to do if/else.

Am I missing something? This seems like it should be extremely basic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Curator` Utility [ZkPaths](http://curator.apache.org/utilities.html), specifically the `mkdirs` function.

Comment: this utility doesn't set the data